# Where is the error in solving the following differential equation, and are there other way $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{9x^2-3}{y^2} - 3x^2y +y$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, definite-integrals

$$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = \frac{9x^2-3}{y^2} - 3x^2y +y,$$ where $y(2) = 3^{1/3}$.

My solution:
\begin{align*}
\mathrm dy &= \left(\frac{9x^2-3}{y^2} - 3x^2y +y\right) \mathrm dx\\
\frac{\mathrm dy}{\frac{3}{y^2} -y} &= (3x^2 -1) \;\mathrm dx \\
\int \frac{\mathrm dy}{\frac{3}{y^2} -y} &= \int (3x^2 -1) \;\mathrm dx \\
\frac{1}{3} \ln\left(3 - y^3\right) &= x^3 -x +c.
\end{align*}
But $\ln(0)$ is undefined.

Comment: Why are you concerned with $\ln{(0)}$? Is there some initial value given?

Comment: @AlejandroJimenezTellado : Because when he puts $x=2$ and $y=3^{1/3}$ (the initial condition), his solution equation becomes $\frac13\ln(3 - 3) = 8-2+c$

Answer (score 6):

$$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = \frac{9x^2-3}{y^2} - 3x^2y +y,$$
$$y^2\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = 3(3x^2-1) - (3x^2 -1)y^3,$$
$$y^2\frac{ dy}{dx} = (3x^2-1)(3 -  y^3)$$
The DE is separable for $y^3\ne 3$:
$$y^2\frac{ dy}{3-y^3} = (3x^2-1)dx$$
$$\dfrac 13\frac{ dy^3}{3-y^3} = (3x^2-1)dx$$
$$\dfrac 13\ln |{3-y^3}| =x^3-x+C$$
Note that $y^3=3$ is also a solution of the DE and it satisgies the given initial condition.
$$y^2\frac{ dy}{dx} = (3x^2-1)(3 -  y^3)$$
$$\implies y^3-3=0$$
The IC imposes:
$$y=+\sqrt[3] {3}\;\;\; \forall \; x $$

Answer (score 4):

Hint.

After multiplication by $y^2$ we have

$$
\frac 13(y^3)' =(9x^2-3) -3x^2 y^3+y^3
$$

now calling $u = y^3$ we follow with

$$
\frac 13u' = (9x^2-3) - (3x^2 - 1)u
$$